# Timeout Operator of RXJS not working as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have to do polling until I get the response as completed. But I also want to do polling only for 2mins and prevent infinite polling for this I am using timeout operator but that doesn't seem to work.

```
     interval(5000)
     .pipe(

    startWith(0),
    switchMap(() => this.someService.getQueueJob(jobId)),
    takeUntil(this.stopPolling),
    timeout(2*60000)
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.jobStatus = res.attributes.status;
    if (this.jobStatus === 'Completed') {
      this.fileUploadStatus = 'success';
      this.stopPolling.next();
    } else if (this.jobStatus === 'Failed') {
      this.fileUploadStatus = 'error';
      this.stopPolling.next();
    }
  });
```

Also I need to throw error when timeout happens and inform the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timer` at startup for timeout:

```js
// set time for timeout
timer(2 * 60000).pipe(
  // trow error when timer emit event after 2 minutes
  map(() => { throw new TimeoutError() }),
  // put startWith operator to start before timer emit timeout event
  startWith(0),
  // switch to polling timer for every 5 second
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000)),
  // get date from http
  switchMap(() => this.someService.getQueueJob(jobId)),
  // stop manually the polling
  takeUntil(this.stopPolling),
).subscribe(
  (data) => console.log(data),
  (error) => {
    if (error instanceof TimeoutError)
      console.log('time out')
    else
      console.log('http error')
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer, but using this approach I am not able to do the polling. The http request is triggered only one time.

Comment: @Gini I have tested it and it is not done only once

Comment: yes sorry I have written the switchMap only once and skipped switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000)), which was causing it to be called only once. Now its working perfectly fine. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [`timeout`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) will be reset everytime there is an emission. So for each emission of the `interval` and the corresponding `this.someService.getQueueJob()` its reset. You could accomplish your requirement with an additional `takeUntil` with the [`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer) function.

Also

1. You say 2 mins timeout in the question, but the code only has a min.?
2. As mentioned by @Chris in the comments, you could replace the `interval(5000)` + `startWith(0)` combo with `timer(0, 5000)`.

```js
timer(0, 5000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.someService.getQueueJob(jobId)),
  takeUntil(this.stopPolling),
  takeUntil(timer(120000))
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

Edit 1: Replace `interval(5000)` + `startWith(0)` with `timer(0, 5000)`

Comment: you can change interval and startWith with timer(0, 5000)

Comment: @Chris: Yes but we do not know if OP actually want to start the polling immediately or start after 5 seconds.

Comment: startsWith starts immediately

Comment: I also need to show error that timeout has happened. Can I throw error in arguments of timer operator? @MichaelD

Comment: @Chris: That is indeed good point. I'll update the answer, thanks

Comment: @Chris  Can we notify the user when this timer completes? In timeout operator for example we can send two arguments one for timelimit and another to throwError which can be handeled.

Comment: @Michale D It seems that timeout error doesn't seem to go inside the error block.

Comment: @Gini: Yes I posted it in haste. I've since removed that update. I'm trying something else.

Comment: @Gini If you switch the order of the two `takeUntil`s, you can use `concatWith(throwError(() => new TimeOutError()))` to throw an error if the stream ends due to the timeout triggering.